# VBA Excel: Evaluate Data Validation Rule

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I am wondering if there is a clean way to evaluate in-cell data validation. It could be either a length check or a drop-down list etc.

I can easily add data validation rules using the below code that validates if the entry is more than 5 characters in cell A1, but is there a way to evaluate it from inside VBA?

```
With Cells(1,1).DataBodyRange.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateTextLength, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
         Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="6"
    .ErrorTitle = "Too Many Characters"
    .ErrorMessage = "The maximum allowed number of characters For this field is 5"
    .ShowError = TRUE
End With
```

Comment: Can you explain what you would like to achieve? How does "evaluate [data validation] from inside VBA" manifest? DV is used for data entry. If the user meets the DV criteria, the entry is accepted. If they don't, the value cannot be confirmed in the cell. What would you want to do in VBA there? What should it do?

Comment: Or do you want to write your own data validation with VBA? In that case, look at Worksheet Change events.

Comment: When you set the cell's validation, Excel creates a `Validation` object for the range and sets properties for that object. In reverse, you can read the properties of an existing validation object, like `Debug.Print Cell.Validation.Formula1`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Data Validation and prefer to re-invent that wheel with VBA, you can use a Worksheet_Change event.

Let the code evaluate the target cell and determine if it meets your criteria. If it doesn't, clear the target cell and display a message.

This approach will effectively remove the user's ability to use Undo, because the VBA will run after each data entry on the whole sheet and will clear the Undo stack. You may want to keep using the built-in Data Validation if you want to retain usability for the end users.